# MySQL Workbench to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am new to MySQL Workbench and AWS RDS. I keep getting the [following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNJ0.png)

I've looked at other questions on stackoverflow + youtube regarding this connection but it still seems to not work. I've made sure that the Public Access option is switched to yes, I've added an Inbound Rule to allow my IP in the Security Group, I've also added an Inbound Rule to accept from anywhere as well. I've recreated the database to see if something may have been bugged, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL workbench. I've deleted any existing profiles under the VPC section and allowed the new database to recreate everything. I've enabled and disabled my Windows firewall as well to make sure that didn't somehow affect anything.

Unfortunately I am still getting the same error, and looking for any assistance. Hopefully it's something simple and I am just missing over it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: Forgot to mention, that I have tried it with the username set to the default "admin" and then I changed it to root as MySQL Workbench had that set in their default connection options.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to login as the `root` user, which is restricted on RDS. You have to login as the user account you specified when creating the RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My apologies as I forgot to mention this in the OP but I changed the name of the user account to root when creating the RDS instance, as before it was set to admin and the error still persisted. I've created a new RDS instance again right now with the default name "admin" set as the username, and the error is still the same.

Comment: @nero are you also configuring SSH settings in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: I am not. For the connection method in MySQL Workbench, I am using "Standard (TCP/IP)." I have not tried to use/modify any SSH settings as the tutorials I followed did not use them.

Comment: OK, it's just weird that the error also says at the end "unable to connect to localhost". Have you tried connecting through the mysql command line, just to narrow things down?

Comment: I have not used the MySQL command line before. Looking at the documentation I use this command: "mysql -h my-end-point-name-from-rds -P 3306 -u admin -p" in the MySQL Command Line client correct? I attempted to do it and this is the following error I got: https://imgur.com/a/ZrTANVB.

Comment: You need to add the DB name to the command line.

Comment: This is the full command I am using based on what I'm seeing in the documentation now: https://imgur.com/a/i2xlLgw. cbox is the db name and everything following the "-" is the endpoint.

Comment: Are you saying you pre-pended the db name to the endpoint or does the name happen to be part of the endpoint address? You still need to add the DB name as the last parameter.

Comment: That's correct, I did pre-pend the db name to the endpoint. I did just try to add the DB name as the last parameter to the end of the command without pre-pending the DB name; however it is still the same error. The full command I am using now is: "mysql -h endpointname -P 3306 -u admin -p cbox;" RDS console is saying that the test1 instance is currently Available as well. This is the configuration page of the instance: https://imgur.com/a/oGKWsSI.

Comment: Why would you prepend anything to the endpoint? The Endpoint is a DNS name and if you change it at all it will never resolve correctly.

Comment: Ah, sorry that makes sense now. I am now using the endpoint name as given by AWS with the DB name added as the last parameter to the command but still the same error.